# Why docker allows removal of other people's containers/images?

Tags: django, docker

So I am new to docker. I have created my own container and image for a Django app to try out. When I use this command in ubuntu, I can see a list of containers and images
`docker ps -a`

and this command to delete a container
`docker rm -f <container_id>`

What puzzles me is that it is possible for me to delete containers and images created by someone else (of course I tried it on "hello-world" projects only).

Why is this allowed? What happen to real production containers/images?

Comment: You are deleting your copy of the image... not the image hosted on docker hub...

Comment: The images that you create on your computer are not put up on docker hub, until you specifically upload it on docker hub. And yes, you can only delete it if it is linked to your account, i.e. you uploaded it.

Comment: The other important detail here is that anyone who can run any `docker` command can pretty trivially root the entire host; Docker doesn't have a notion of "user" or "ownership" of a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze: Does it mean that if I run a container as user `x`, user `y` can control my container?

Comment: Any user can use `docker` to control any container.  Any user can `docker run -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers` to take over the whole system.

Comment: Now I am confused. Is there a good documentation on this topic that I can read up on? It seems pretty useless if, for uploaded containers/images, anyone can just control it besides the owner.